# Logging module name/line of one stack level higher in Python

Tags: python, logging

I wrote a wrapper logger class which keeps the return value of `self.logger=getLogger(...)` in an attribute and calls logging requests accordingly (`self.logger.info(...)`). In the handler formats I use the tags `%(module)s` and `%(lineno)d` to print module name and line number. Unfortunately I only get the wrappers module name in line number since that is where the final call to the logging system happens.

Do you know how to report the function with its module name and line number which calls the wrapper instead?

Comment: Since loggers are singletons you don't gain anything by keeping them in a wrapper instance. I would get rid of the wrapper - what does it buy you?

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that having a wrapper as described is a bit silly, I just solved this problem myself for when using a lambda to wrap calls that have similar, long, and annoying parameters in "extras".  Having not found a good answer elsewhere I thought I'd share.

(This is a Python 3.2.3 solution.  And again, it's specific to a lambda wrapper rather than a class wrapper.)

Step one: look up the Python source code, find ..Lib\logging\__init__.py,
Step b: find the "Logger.findCaller" method, copy it into a utility file somewhere, renamed to, say, "find_caller_no_lambda".
Next step: remove "self" from the method signature, prefix any module level attributes, and make the following change, modified to taste:

```
#       if filename == _srcfile: # Original line
        if filename == logging._srcfile or f.f_code.co_name == "<lambda>": # New line
            f = f.f_back # Original line for context.
            continue # Original line for context.
```

Step the last: wherever your logger is declared, insert the following line:

```
my_logger.findCaller = util.find_caller_no_lambda
```

Voilà.

(And of course you can just subclass Logger for that one little change if you feel like it.)

Addendum:

Conversely, you can rewrite Logger.makeRecord to remove the check against key conflicts in extras, and add the line numbers, function name, etc, to the log call itself/detect such things in your wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

It seems from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug) that starting with 3.8 there is an optional argument `stacklevel` for skipping a number of stack levels and logging the previous call position

Test snippet:

```
import logging

def super_debug(msg):
  for stacklevel in range(1, 7):
    logging.debug(f"stacklevel={stacklevel} : {msg}", stacklevel=stacklevel)

def test():
  logging.debug('direct debug at line 9')
  super_debug('super_debug call at line 10')

logging.basicConfig(
  level=logging.DEBUG,
  format="%(filename)s:%(lineno)-2s - %(funcName)11s| %(message)s"
)

test()
```

produces the following output on Python 3.8:

```
logging_test.py:9  -        test| direct debug at line 9
logging_test.py:6  - super_debug| stacklevel=1 : super_debug call at line 10
logging_test.py:6  - super_debug| stacklevel=2 : super_debug call at line 10
logging_test.py:10 -        test| stacklevel=3 : super_debug call at line 10
logging_test.py:17 -    <module>| stacklevel=4 : super_debug call at line 10
logging_test.py:6  - super_debug| stacklevel=5 : super_debug call at line 10
logging_test.py:6  - super_debug| stacklevel=6 : super_debug call at line 10
```

with `stacklevel=3` the `super_debug()` function mimics `logging.degug()` run in the `test()` function in terms of logged filename/function/line position

Answer (score 0):

It is in Python Frame object. http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html

Comment: But how do I make the logging system use it? Only the handlers know the formatting string and they resolve it.